# Question involving the Chern character from the book "Fibre Bundles"

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

On page 311 of Dale Husemöller's book *[Fibre Bundles](http://books.google.com/books?id=DPr_BSH89cAC)* in [Theorem 11.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=DPr_BSH89cAC&pg=PA311) he has
the following
commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}
& &  K(BG)\\
&\nearrow &\downarrow\\
R(G)&\longrightarrow & H^*(BG,\mathbb Q)
\end{array} $$
Here $G$ is a compact connected Lie group, $BG$ is its classifying space, and $R(G)$
the representation ring.
The map from $R(G) \rightarrow K(BG)$ is the map which takes a representation $\rho:
G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$ to the associated vector bundle
$EG\times_{\rho}\mathbb C^n$.  The map from $K(BG)\rightarrow H^*(BG,\mathbb Q)$ is
the usual
Chern character and the map $R(G)\rightarrow H^*(BG,\mathbb Q)$ is a map he calls
$ch^*$ which he says has the
following property: given a $T$-module ($T\subset G$ the maximal torus) $M$ then
$$ch^*M=e^{-\tau (M)}$$
where $\tau: H^1(T,\mathbb Z)\rightarrow H^2(BG, \mathbb Z)$ is the transgression map.

My question is: why the minus sign in the definition of $ch^*$?

---

**Edit:** (TB) here's a screen shot of the relevant page from Google Books

[image: Husemöller, page 311]

Comment: Thank you for adding the screen shot.